# Is there any atomic set operation that returns the old value in C?

Tags: c, atomic

I am looking for some `atomic_set`-like function that sets the variable's value atomically and, at the same time, it returns the previous value similar to the `compare_and_swap`.

Here is what I expect:

```
int old_val = atomic_set(mem_address, 10);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C11 `<stdatomic.h>` defines `atomic_exchange()` and `atomic_exchange_explicit()` that perform this operation.

The `atomic_exchange_explicit()` form allows you to specify the memory ordering required (the plain `atomic_exchange()` uses the strongest memory ordering `memory_order_seq_cst`).

Comment: Didn't know if any such thing existed. Thanks +1 :-)